# Dynamic for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to calculate certain array but the issue that I am facing is that array is changing in each iteration. 
I want to print

```
for n=1 
    s(1)u(1)
for n=2
    s(2)u(1)+(s(1)-s(2))u(2)
for n=3
    s(3)u(1)+(s(2)-s(3))u(2)+(s(1)-s(2))u(3)
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on your setup. If you just want to do a matrix/vector operation without many loops, note that this looks almost like an inner product between `s` reversed and `u` except some terms have been turned into the difference. If I understand your equations, it looks like this:

```
N = 12;
s_all = 1:N;
u_all = 7:N+6


for M = 1:N
   s = s_all(1:M);
   u = u_all(1:M);

   ds = s - [s(2:end) 0];
   result = u*ds(end:-1:1)'
end
```

Note my data is a row vector.

this works fine if `N` doesn't grow too big, if you don't know the final size of `N` at the start, or if the values of `s` and `u` all change at each iteration.

Depending on the sizes of your data, if `u` and `s` have the same prior values at each iteration you might see better results by preallocating `u` and `s` above the for loop and then bring in new values one at a time rather than copying over new `s` and `u` and recalculating the entire `ds` value.

Like this:

```
s = nan(1,N);
u = nan(1,N);
ds = nan(1,N);

for M = 1:N
   s(M) = s_all(M);
   u(M) = u_all(M);

   if(M>1)
     ds(M-1) = s(M-1) - s(M);
   end
   ds(M) = s(M);
   result = u(1:M)*ds(M:-1:1)'
end
```

Comment: You are overwriting `result` at every iteration in your loop...?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to retain it you could write `result(M)=blablabla`

Comment: if you don't want to retain it then why have the loop? Or rather, why is that line in the loop?

Comment: One would assume @Ali has a plan for using it inside the loop or after the loop. The code is mean to illustrate an efficient solution to the relationship of the varying size input and output. At first it may appear you need a `for` loop to construct result at each iteration, but this solution shows that you can construct a vector `ds` and reverse `s` to perform a vector operation. The `result` must be calculated each time. Actual use of `result` will depend on the asker's application.